# Trouble debugging nodeJS with nodeclipse (Failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM)

Tags: node.js, debugging, nodeclipse

Hoping someone can help.  I've been through every forum, the online help, every youtube, and every example to find an answer.  This either means it's incredibly nuanced or incredibly simple and I'm just missing something that seems to work for everyone.

```
Nodeclipse/chromedevtools failed to connect to Standalone V8 VM 
( Check Help (F1) and Support http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support )
. Info:
connect timed out
```

I get the above error when I use nodeclipse to debug a node app using the right-click menu on the project.  DEBUG AS -> NODE APPLICATION.

When I RUN AS -> NODE APPLICATION, it launches just fine.  But when I run with debug-as, I get that error and the debug info looks like.. (or not.. I can't post images... but it terminates the V8 VM entry)

I've installed JDK 8, the most recent NodeJS, the express packages, enide studio from nodeclipse.org, and followed the instructions to build a starter app (new - express project), then attempted to debug that app with debug-as->node application.

I can successfully debug a node instance (my actual project) that I start from the command line, and it lets me step through the virtual project files, etc..  but I was looking for the "all in one" nature where I am debugging the same files I'm editing and can launch/test it all from within eclipse.

- Win 7, 64bit
- JDK 1.8.0_11 64bit
- node 0.10.29 64bit
- nodeclipse/enide studio  2014-011-20140228-win64

I've tried it with JDK1.7 as well (64 bit).

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Zig

Answer (score 1):

While the issue happened before it is hard to reproduce on other machines.
More stats is needed.

http://www.nodeclipse.org/#support gives links to Online Help (the same as built-in by F1)

in particular
https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.help/contents/run.md
and https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/blob/master/org.nodeclipse.help/contents/debug.md

Have you tried to

to run `node --debug-brk app.js` first, and then again in Eclipse/Enide Studio ? [#107](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/107)

Comment: could you explain what you mean by "and then again in eclipse"? I've the ran command `node --debug-brk app.js` and then it says `Debugger listening on port 5858`. If I then go on to debug the project again in eclipse I get an error which basically says that only one node app can be running at  a time.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some luck getting around this error by:

1. Right clicking in the server and selecting run as -> node application
2. Navigating in Firefox to the address where my server is listening
3. Stopping the server in the console
4. Right clicking in the server and selecting debug as -> node application

I also created a new perspective called "visualstudio" and do no switch perspectives between development and debug (though I doubt perspectives have much to do with the issue)

Using this approach, I get an interesting anamoly where the debugger breaks on line 1 when the server starts, and I then have to click resume.  However, after resuming, execution only stops when a request hits a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run the command to debug the node.js file:

node --debug-brk yourfilename.js (this is not working now)

node --inspect-brk yourfilename.js